# incorporating a distribution constraint in a minimisation objective

Tags: lagrange-multipliers

For a given (convex) hypothesis $h \in \mathcal{H}$, and the variables $X \in \mathcal{X}$ and $Y \in \mathcal{Y}$ I have the following optimisation problem:

\begin{equation}
\min_{p(X,Y)} \int_{\mathcal{X}}\int_{\mathcal{Y}}p(x,y)\ell(h(x),y) \,dy \,dx
\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad -p(X=x,Y=y) +\beta \leq 0, \quad   \forall (x,y) \in \mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}, \beta>0 \\
\quad  \int_{\mathcal{X}}\int_{\mathcal{Y}}p(x,y) \,dy \,dx -1=0
\end{equation}

How I should incorporate the constraint $\forall (x,y) \in \mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y} $ in the objective to correctly form the Lagrangian? Is the following correct:

\begin{equation}
L(p,  \lambda)= \int_{\mathcal{X}}\int_{\mathcal{Y}}p(x,y)\ell(h(x),y) +\mu p(x,y) \,dy \,dx + \sum_{(x,y) \in \mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}} \lambda_{(x,y)}(\beta -p(X=x,Y=y) ) - \mu
\end{equation}
Should the constraint be written as a double integral?

Comment: Are you sure that's the constraint you want?  That $p(x,y) \geq \beta > 0$?  Are you confident that the resulting distribution will integrate to 1?   Also, depending on how you are actually going to optimize it, you may be able to get away with one Lagrangian by using $\min p(x,y) \geq \beta$ as the only constraint.

Comment: Thanks @jbowman, I neglected that the resulting distribution should be integrating to one! How could the $\min p(x,y) \geq \beta$ be integrated in the Lagrangian though ? I have to solve this analytically first, so I am not confident that $\lambda\beta-\lambda\min p(x,y)$ will be easy (not that the previous version was better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably remove the lower bound constraint by noting that since all the probabilities are $\geq \beta$, I can optimize over the difference $p^*(x,y) = p(x,y) - \beta$ instead of over $p(x,y)$:

$$\begin{aligned}
\min_{p(X,Y)} \int_{\mathcal{X}}\int_{\mathcal{Y}}p(x,y)\ell(\cdot) \,dy \,dx &= \min_{p^*(X,Y)} \int_{\mathcal{X}}\int_{\mathcal{Y}}(p^*(x,y)+\beta)\ell(\cdot) \,dy \,dx \\
&= \min_{p^*(X,Y)} \int_{\mathcal{X}}\int_{\mathcal{Y}}p^*(x,y)\ell(\cdot) \,dy \,dx + C
\end{aligned}$$

where $C$ is a constant ($\beta$ times the integral of $\ell(\cdot))$ and can be ignored.

Now, with the constraint that $p^*(x,y) \geq 0$, which is natural in many approaches, you've satisfied the $\beta$ inequality automatically.  The "integrate to one" constraint then becomes

$$\int_{\mathcal{X}}\int_{\mathcal{Y}}p^*(x,y)\,dx\,dy = 1 - \beta\int_{\mathcal{X}}\int_{\mathcal{Y}}\,dx\,dy$$

which term on the right should be easily found.

Comment: can you please give more details on why we do not need to add the constraint $1- \beta \geq p^*(x,y) \geq 0$ in the objective?

Comment: Why does $1-\beta$ have to be $\geq p^*(x,y)$?  The last line ensures that $p(x,y)$ integrates to one, which is all we need.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But this assumes that the lower bound $p^*(x,y)\geq0$ is also true. How can does the problem definition ensure that the lower bound is met? else am I missing something here?

Comment: Depending on the optimization algorithm, that may be a standard sort of constraint that is satisfied.   Otherwise, you can replace $p^*(x,y)$ with $\exp \{p'(x,y)\}$, where $p' = \log  p$, which will automatically satisfy the constraint.

Comment: This results in the objective being $\min\limits_{p'(X,Y)}  \int_{\mathcal{X}} \int_{\mathcal{Y}} e^{p'(x,y)} \ell(h(x),y) \,dy  \,dx $ and the constraint is  $\int_{\mathcal{X}} \int_{\mathcal{Y}} e^{p'(x,y)} \,dy  \,dx =1 - \beta \int_{\mathcal{X}} \int_{\mathcal{Y}}   \,dy  \,dx $, correct?

Comment: Yes... but the constraint this enforces is actually $p(x,y) > \beta$, as it happens, which may be important.